# New user on askubuntu, would like to help but cannot

Tags: discussion

As a new user on askubuntu, I want to contribute to a thread with valuable information for those who are still struggling

However, I cannot because the thread already has answers (or so it appears). Certainly in my case and many others, those answers haven't dealt with specific cases and in fact there are answers which are off-topic and in danger of derailing the thread completely

For the curious, the thread is https://askubuntu.com/a/126381/1137630

It's a power down issue where the PC fires up immediately after shutdown. In my case, the situation is resolved by disabling an option in the BIOS relating to "Resume from S5 by #PME"

It's not exactly a solution because it obviously prevents resume in instances where this is desirable behaviour, but it's a legitimate workaround for those awaiting a more elegant solution

This is definitely not a problem in Windows (on the same PC) and it certainly has nothing to do with failure to shutdown because of hung services or misbehaving drivers (as the thread is more recently veering towards)

For the even more curious, the mobo is an Asus M5A88-V EVO on kernel 5.40-48, but has been an issue since 4.15

Is there any way I can contribute or may I expect a moderator to intervene on my behalf? Presumably this is a reputation issue?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to add an answer or a comment?  If it's not a true solution then it shouldn't be posted as an answer and instead be posted as a comment, however you need 50 rep to get to the point of commenting on threads.  And as for adding an answer, well, you need to get past the new user restrictions and contribute first elsewhere - that question has had a HUGE number of not-an-answer posts and has been protected for a long time - it's protecting 'new users' because the vast majority have been poor/non answers and were flagged/deleted.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you for your input Thomas. Also thank you Mark for the link, that does shed some light on the situation. The reputation issue may protect the thread from spamming and poor quality answers, but it also prevents external users (directed by search engine) from contributing. Would you agree there ought to be less automation and more moderation; after all only warriors kill trolls, rules just slow them down!

Comment: The issue is not trolls, it is none answers, things like "I have this issue too", eight of which have been deleted (3 today). That is just not what the answer section of this site is for, it is for answers. The protection is used because otherwise users would have to keep manually deleting stuff form the question and that can take a lot of time and there are hundreds of thousands of questions to moderate. All you need is 10 rep on the site (a single upvote on any post you make or five approved edits) to answer that question, the requirements for getting round the protection are very low..

Comment: Here is a list of things you can do to earn that bit of reputation https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation it won't take long and is a small ask for something that keeps the quality of the site high.

Comment: Also I just noticed that question is eight and a half years old, any fix you know for a modern version may simply not work on 12.04 as that is EOL and not supported nor does it even have a repository anymore. If you really want to contribute, you can ask and then answer your own new question based on what ever version of Ubuntu you currently have, that would be a lot more useful than answering that old question.

Comment: Many thanks Mark for your assistance. I now see what you're up against, as a contributor or moderator. Ok, they're technically not trolls, but they are a subspecies; some sort of hobgoblin. As for the vintage of the page, I'm not convinced it makes any difference what version of the OS was at the time. Fundamentally, if a bug or a special case isn't fixed then it remains a continuous problem that transcends time! In my case, using relatively old hardware, vintage answers are more likely to be relevant than new. I completely take your point, of course. Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: I think that posting an up-to-date answer to an old question, in general, is heroic

Comment: We can be heroes, even if it's just for one day